# How to test installation and working of a Google workspace web app without publishing?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workspace, google-apps-marketplace

I am trying to install a unpublished web app into my domain. I have created the app under the same admin account of my domain. But I can't be able to install the app in my account. I have searched the internet and found out that you can test those app using a "Test installation flow"/"Integrate with google" button in App configuration before. But now there is no button like that and I don't know how to install it.

I make that app publicly available because I need that app to be publicly available. Can someone tell me how to install it as if there is any new flows to install it?

During searching the internet I came across this documentation with using AppsScript.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

But this includes Apps Script in it. But I didn't need Script to create an app as I create the app in Cloud Console.

Looking for a faster reply guys, as I need this now for my project. Thank You.